# Передать по Wi-Fi сообщение на Android

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, socket.io, cordova

Нужно передать сообщение с компьютера, там клиент на NodeJS (у меня). Получатель, клиент Android на JavaScript (cordova). Пробую передать с помощью сокетов.

**Код сервера на NodeJS:**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.send("Test_Message");
});
```

**Код клиента:**

```
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
  socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
      var di = document.getElementById("subscribe").innerHTML = msg + " ";
    });
  });
```

При эмулировании в браузере (cordova run browser) - работает. Эмуляция приложения на компьютере и запуск на устройстве ничего не дают.

Может в адресе нужно писать не localhost?

Comment: _Javascript_ на Андроиде?? Может, Java на Андроиде или просто Javascript, где угодно? Вероятно, Вам посоветуют TCP-IP использовать.

Comment: Клиент androida на javascript, в этом вся проблема)

Comment: На сайте или какое-то языковое портирование?

Comment: В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, какие технологии используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.

Comment: Нативное приложение на Cordova на JavaScript. Нужно подключившись к сети получить ответ в виде сообщения.

Comment: *Может в адресе нужно писать не localhost?* — да, вашему клиенту явно надо указывать имя/адрес компьютера, на котором работает ваш сервер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено. Нужно на устройстве прописывать в путь ip шлюза.